# check for capital letters in mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have a table with some email fields. Some email records are in capital letters and some in camel case . Now i have to convert all the emails with capital letters to small letters. I can do that with a PHP script by fetching every record then checking it for any capital letters and then converting it to lowercase if any capital letter is found.

Is there any way in Mysql with which we can get only those records that contains capital letters in them and not all?? This way i will be spared by executing each and every record. Iam looking for a way in Mysql with which we can check for capital letters in a record in query itself . Any suggestions??

Comment: What do you mean by "email records"? If you're talking about ADDR_SPECs, then you might want to consider that while domains are not case-sensitive, mailbox names *sometimes* are.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change the collation to a case-sensitive collation.

But really, how long will this query take?

```
update `table` set email = lower(email)
```

Edit: update only records containing not only lower case emails:

```
update 
    `table`
set
    email = lower(email) 
where
    email <> lower(email)
collate
    latin1_general_cs
```

You can test this by selecting them first:

```
select 
    *
from
    `table`
where
    email <> lower(email)
collate
    latin1_general_cs
limit 
    10
```

Comment: i dont want to touch those email id's which dont have any capital letter as there's a huge data in this table and traversing all is not a good solution here

Comment: what i was missing till now was "collate latin1_general_cs"  .... what is this doing specifically in this query...it would be great if you can explain this too :)

Comment: A [collation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-examples.html) in an RDBMS defines how queries against a given data set are handled. CI stands for Case Insensitive, so "foo" matches "foo", "FOO", "Foo" and so on. CS is Case Sensitive, so there must be an exact match. De default collations used in most database systems are case insensitive. See also [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/case-sensitivity.html).

Comment: @developer - If it is one off exercise - what is the harm? Just come in very early one morning.